# Bookmarking function django/python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm looking to create a model for users to bookmark a recipe. I have the below:

models.py

```
class RecipeBookmark(models.Model):

    recipe = models.ForeignKey(
        Recipe, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="bookmarks"
    )
    bookmarked_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    bookmarked_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = models.User
            fields = ["username", "email", "date_joined"]

class RecipeBookmarkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bookmarked_by = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.RecipeBookmark
        fields = ["recipe", "bookmarked_by", "bookmarked_at"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context["request"]
        ModelClass = self.Meta.model

        instance = ModelClass.objects.create(
            **validated_data, **{"bookmarked_by": request.user}
        )
        return instance
```

views.py

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
class RecipeBookmarkView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.RecipeBookmark.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecipeBookmarkSerializer
```

urls.py

```
path("recipes/bookmarks/", PublishedRecipeBookmarkView.as_view()),
```

I want to perform a lookup, given the recipe id through a POST request, to add the user to the bookmarks field, if the user already exists in the bookmarks field, to remove that user form the field (remove the bookmark). Many users can bookmark a given recipe.

Also, How can a lookup be performed to return recipes that a logged in user has bookmarked via an api endpoint?

Current error with get_or_create():

Error: Internal Server Error

Response body
Download
AttributeError at /api/recipes/bookmarks/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `recipe` on serializer `RecipeBookmarkSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `tuple` instance.
Original exception text was: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'recipe'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your serializer to ensure that only one bookmark is created per user per recipe, you can use [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context["request"]
        ModelClass = self.Meta.model

        instance = ModelClass.objects.get_or_create(
            **validated_data, **{"bookmarked_by": request.user}
        )
        return instance
```

If the bookmark is already present, it will just grab it and return.

> Also, How can a lookup be performed to return recipes that a logged in user has bookmarked via an api endpoint?

To support this, you can define [`ListCreateAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) to your view and override the queryset like so:

```
class RecipeBookmarkView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(bookmarked_by=self.request.user)
```

This will then support getting all the `RecipeBookmark` that is owned by the current user via `GET` requests on `recipes/bookmarks/`

Comment: I changed the create to get_or_create and keep getting the following when attempting a POST:

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `recipe` on serializer `RecipeBookmarkSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `tuple` instance.
Original exception text was: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'recipe'.

RecipeSerializer has the field recipe, so I'm not sure why it would say this:
fields = ["recipe", "bookmarked_by", "bookmarked_at"]

Comment: In addition, if this works it would solve the one bookmark per user per recipe issue, to remove a bookmark, would i use a DestroyApiView?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest using `DestroyApiView`, and just specifying the bookmark id you want to delete

Comment: Can you share the request data you used when you get that error

Comment: And if possible update the question with the traceback

Comment: The request body is just this:

{
  "recipe": 1
}

as bookmarked_by is set through the def create and bookmarked_at is auto added via the model

If i change it back to get instead of get_or_create, it returns the below

{
  "recipe": 1,
  "bookmarked_by": {
    "username": "username",
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "date_joined": "2021-07-25T11:57:04.514790Z"
  },
  "bookmarked_at": "2021-07-26T07:39:52.895229Z"
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235295/discussion-between-jbiz-and-bdbd).