# How to set url id to a specific field django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm looking to create a model for users to bookmark a recipe. I have the below, where a recipe value is passed through a POST request:

models.py

```
class PublishedRecipeBookmark(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(
        PublishedRecipe, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="bookmarks"
    )
    bookmarked_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    bookmarked_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class PublishedRecipeBookmarkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bookmarked_by = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.PublishedRecipeBookmark
        fields = ["recipe", "bookmarked_by", "bookmarked_at"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context["request"]
        ModelClass = self.Meta.model

        instance = ModelClass.objects.create(
            **validated_data, **{"bookmarked_by": request.user}
        )
        return instance
```

views.py

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
class PublishedRecipeBookmarkView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.PublishedRecipeBookmark.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PublishedRecipeBookmarkSerializer
```

urls.py

```
path("published-recipes/bookmarks", PublishedRecipeBookmarkView.as_view()),
```

I want to change the url to something like this, so that the recipeid is passed through the url (int:id).

urls.py

```
path("published-recipes/bookmarks/<int:id>", PublishedRecipeBookmarkView.as_view()),
```

How can I achieve this so that the view recognises the id as a recipeid for a PublishedRecipe (a foreign key relationship is established in the model)?

Updating as this was a different question and the above is already answered.

Comment: It would make more sense to put the recipe id in the request body, as already expected in your current serializer. Is that not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make more sense to put the recipe id in the request body, as already expected in your current serializer.

As a convention:

```
published-recipes/bookmarks/<int:id>
```

`id` here would correspond to the bookmarks id, and treating it as recipe id would IMO be bad practice and will confuse others who will work on this code.

But if you are sure and you really want to do this, you can override the view's `create` method:

```py
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
class PublishedRecipeBookmarkView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.PublishedRecipeBookmark.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PublishedRecipeBookmarkSerializer

    def create(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
        ... # do what you want with id here
```

or get it from `kwargs`:

```py
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs.get('id')
```

Comment: It does work currently, however, im having issues achieving my final functionality which is a bookmarking function. so i thought of trying to parse the recipe id , but rethinking it i cant imagine how that solves my problem.

here;s the problem I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68516385/bookmarking-function-django-python

Essentially I am trying to have users bookmark a particular recipe. In its current setting, it just keeps posting a request to bookmark, im having trouble setting it so that it removes a bookmark if it already exists. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve?

Comment: `im having issues achieving my final functionality which is a bookmarking function` -- Can you update your question specifically with what's the expected output and what you are currently getting?

Comment: sorry I inadvertently clicked enter, I updated the comment above with a link to a description of the issue. im not sure if it will let me update the question as its similar to another one i have open. However i'll try updating this question

Comment: I added a separate answer for that link you shared. Is the current answer here still relevant?

Comment: Yes the current answer here answered my initial question. So ill mark that as answered and ill take a look at the other link to attempt your solution. Thanks!